# Return a blank cell if the cell is blank

Tags: excel

I am currently using this formula:

```
=IF([@Vacaciones2]<>"",[@Vacaciones2],"")*IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Posicion + Nivel]],Table3[#All],2,FALSE),"")
```

It is working fine if @Vacaciones2 has a value, however the problem is that if @Vacaciones2 = blank, then it should return me just a blank cell and not #VALUE!

What am I doing wrong????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `""` when it is blank, then you try to multiply it by a number.  `""*1` will cause the `#VALUE` error.

Instead move the full formula inside the IF:

```
=IFERROR(IF([@Vacaciones2]<>"",[@Vacaciones2]*VLOOKUP([@[Posicion + Nivel]],Table3[#All],2,FALSE),""),"")
```